# Knowing the XOR of odd Number

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, xor

Given an array of odd numbers or even numbers, how can one efficiently get pairs of this array whose XOR == 2?

For example:

```
arr = [4,10,2,6,8]
pairs are: [(4,6), (8,10)] #4^6 == 2, 8^10 == 2
```

Or:

```
arr = [5,9,3,7,11]
pairs are: [(9,11), (5,7),]
```

I did this to get them (brute-force)

```
for i in combinations(inev,2):#inev is the list of indices (positions of the numbers in the array)

        if not (arr[i[0]] ^ arr[i[1]]) & 1 and (arr[i[0]] ^ arr[i[1]]) == 2:

                print arr[i[0]], arr[i[1]] #I print the pair
```

Comment: If two numbers are both odd or both even, and have a XOR of 2, then the have a difference of two - in other words, there cannot be any input numbers with a value between them.  So, you can just sort the array, and make a single pass thru it - a number's pair is either the next number in the array, or it has no pair at all.

Comment: sort the array first...

Comment: Alright. But will sorting the array modify the results of an unsorted array? i.e, will the results gotten from sorting the array differ from those gotten for the array when left unsorted?